# Bootstrap modal stacking removes browser scroll bar

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, modal-dialog, viewport

So i have a little bit of bootstrap modal stacking, following this example:
http://miles-by-motorcycle.com/fv-b-8-670/stacking-bootstrap-dialogs-using-event-callbacks

Now while the example works as intended, 
the first modal can have the potential to expand the height of the page requiring scrolling.

How ever if this is the case, and a smaller modal is stack on top, the scroll bar is removed,
and continues to not appear even when the smaller modal is dismissed.

http://jsfiddle.net/8N3T8/1/

```
<button name="openModalOne">Open 1</button>
<div id="modalone" class="modal" role="dialog" >
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h3>Modal 1</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body" style="height: 2000px">
                <button name="stackone">Stack me</button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button name="closeone">Button 1</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="modaltwo" class="modal" role="dialog" >
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h3>Modal 1</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                This is a stacked modal            
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button name="closetwo">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.modal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function( event ) {
        $(this).removeClass('fv-modal-stack');
        $('body').data( 'fv_open_modals', $('body').data('fv_open_modals')-1);
    });

    $('.modal').on('shown.bs.modal', function(){
        if ( typeof ( $("body").data( 'fv_open_modals' ) ) == 'undefined')
        {
            $('body').data( 'fv_open_modals', 0 );
        }
        if($(this).hasClass('fv-modal-stack'))
        {
            return;
        }
        $(this).addClass('fv-modal-stack');
        $('body').data('fv_open_modals', $('body').data('fv_open_modals')+1);
        $(this).css('z-index', 1040 +(10*$('body').data('fv_open_modals')));
        $('.modal-backdrop').not('.fv-modal-stack')
            .css('z-index', 1039 + (10*$('body').data('fv_open_modals')));
        $('.modal-backdrop').not('fv-modal-stack')
            .addClass('fv-modal-stack');
    }); 

    $("button[name='openModalOne']").on('click', function(){
        $("#modalone").modal('show'); 
    });

    $("button[name='stackone']").on('click', function(){
       $("#modaltwo").modal('show');
    });
    $("button[name='closetwo']").on('click', function(){
       $("#modaltwo").modal('hide');
    });
    $("button[name='closeone']").on('click', function(){
       $("#modalone").modal('hide');
    });
});
```

Is there a way to instruct the browser the true height of the content?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

we can listen to '[hide](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals)' event on modal 2. and get back the scroll bar with jquery [`css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/)  method:

```
// on 'hide' event in modal 2
$('#modaltwo').on('hide.bs.modal', function () {
    $("#modalone").css("overflow-y", "auto"); // 'auto' or 'scroll'
});
```

**demo: http://jsfiddle.net/8N3T8/2/**

Comment: Beautiful sir! I would vote up, but apparently i am not reputable enough! Thanks a lot!

Comment: For me this worked when I put it at the end of the hidden.bs.modal event. Also, I changed the jQuery selectors so it will work without the need to know the ids:

`$('.modal.fv-modal-stack').css('overflow-y', 'auto');`

Comment: simple and easy solution

Answer (score 2):

Solution provided by @meni181818 works well but it creates additional vertical scroll-bar. After a lot of search i ended up with following solution that works perfectly without any additional vertical scroll-bar.

```
$("your second modal id").on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {

        if($('.modal.in').css('display') == 'block'){

            $('body').addClass('modal-open');
        }

    });
```

Comment: Great! This worked perfectly for me, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $body = $('body');
    var originalBodyPad = parseInt($body.css('padding-right'), 10);

    var measureScrollbar = function () {
        // almost exact copy of source of modal.js
        var scrollDiv = document.createElement('div');
        scrollDiv.className = 'modal-scrollbar-measure';
        $body.append(scrollDiv);
        var scrollbarWidth = scrollDiv.offsetWidth - scrollDiv.clientWidth;
        $body[0].removeChild(scrollDiv);
        return scrollbarWidth;
    };

    $(".modal").on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
        var $visible_modals = $('.modal:visible');
        if( $visible_modals.length > 0 ) {
            $body.css('padding-right', originalBodyPad + measureScrollbar());
            $('body', document).addClass('modal-open');
        }
    });
});
```

Have a look at the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/grbrLrdw/

You can also use my bootstrap-multi-modal fix, found here: https://github.com/sbreiler/bootstrap-multi-modals